# Stylesheet conversion for wordpress cannot use php tags

Tags: php, wordpress

Im learning wordpress and I am using this youtube tutorial as reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZCFRQAcqLU

Im trying to convert my php code from

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link <?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>rel="stylesheet">
```

After conversion, the page returns a blank page. I noticed that I cant use any php tags for this and I dont know why. it is already in my C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\wpbootstrap_master\index.php file. Any my Xamp is running fine. Help please

Comment: I'm not sure how wordpress works, but shouldn't you echo the `bloginfo(....)` ?

Comment: Enable error reporting and see what errors you are getting, we can't do much with just a blank page as it covers just about everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Use php code in href tag l

```
ie. href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"
```

Comment: Hi! Code only answers aren't really optimal for SO or future visitors, could you please elaborate on what you have changed / How your code is different from OP's and what OP did wrong?

Comment: <link href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

use php code in href tag like this href="<?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"

Comment: I already tried the echo command before (using the code you gave me) but this still wont work.

Comment: @HaninderSingh I ment update your answer, there's a edit button you can click to update it with.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the question, turns out that the code is fine and it has no error. But since this is word press I needed to run it to its own server.